# Mined blocks don't show up in storage container?

Tags: space-engineers

I am trying to make a ship that has 2 mining units in the front.

Attached directly to these mining unit are conveyor pipe's which are connected to a medium storage unit.

After a bit of mining, nothing shows up in the storage unit.

I tried using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSg0jLKNeHo) video on Youtube, but it did not solve my problem.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We9la1sApAs&list=UUVVW2b5wuXGpdM5-EQhxQQw) is a video of my ship while mining, and at the end of the video I show the conveyor pipes, etc.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which YouTube tutorials did you use? You mention that you looked at some.

Comment: A Basic Mining Ship Tutorial from w4stedspace. But even if I have made a mistake in that ship, what is wrong with the ship that I am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
The ship itself is fine, but I needed to turn the miners on in the control panel, not from dragging it into my inventory and then using my mouse to turn it in and off.